# Подскажите, как сделать правильно подобную вещь (html, css, js)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover

возник немаловажный вопрос, на который у меня пока что нет ответа.
Мне нужна помощь, у меня на сайте присутствуют блоки в каталоге, которые при наведении, раскрывают содержимое, цена, описание и прочее, но, зачастую, случается так, что текст вылазит за рамки самого изображения и этого блока. Мне нужно, чтобы он обрезался доходя до границ блока, но, из-за того, что блок имеет адаптивные настройки, границы просто растягивается. Как бы я не пытался самостоятельно разобраться с этим, всё было напрасно.

Вот исходный код, надеюсь, что вы поможете.

```css
.product img {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 314px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.product {
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}

.product .product-description {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.product:hover .product-description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.product-catalog {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-catalog">
    <div class="product">
       <a href="#">
          <div class="product-description">
           <a href="#">
            <span class="title">Название</span>
            <span class="price">Цена</span>
            <span class="categories">Категории</span>
            <span class="description">Описание</span>
           </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=8790ab6b964cc36b189ecb873ff27273&n=13">
       </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте рабочий пример кода с проблемой, через сниппет.

Comment: http://test.aokesu.beget.tech

вот ссылка на сайт, можете посмотреть, что да как (смотреть на "вскорее на сайте" и "рекомендации")

Comment: если быть точнее, мне нужно, чтобы текс с описанием находился по середине и, в не зависимости от его количества, прерывался доходя до определённых границ

Comment: что значит "прерывался" ? @AokeSu

Comment: имеется ввиду `overflow: hidden` для родителя?

Comment: ну, как объяснить.. Например.. у вас есть блок шириной 100px, когда текст доходит до границы, вместо скролла, текст просто прервётся, а на конце поставиться троеточие, насколько помню, есть свойство css, делающее это, но на моём примере оно не поможет, уже пытался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать просто `overflow:hidden` и ограничить максимальную высоту.
НО!!! "..." добавляться не будет. только средствами css для многострочного блока этого сделать нельзя, но можно использовать js. Например, вот этот скрипт - https://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Пример без скрипта:

```css
/*Start*/
.product:hover .product-description {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*End*/

.product img {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 314px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.product {
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}

.product .product-description {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.product:hover .product-description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.product-catalog {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-catalog">
    <div class="product">
       <a href="#">
          <div class="product-description">
           <div class="link">
            <span class="title">Название</span>
            <span class="price">Цена</span>
            <span class="categories">Категории</span>
            <span class="description">Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание</span>
           </div>
          </div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
       </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что бы скрыть текст за пределами родителя используйте `overflow: hidden`, что бы текст не переносился на новую строку `white-space: nowrap`
p.s. Ваш `html` код нужно переделать так как он содержит ошибки. Не вкладывайте тег `<a>` в `<a>`.

```css
/*Start*/
.product-description {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
.link {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}
/*End*/

.product img {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 314px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.product {
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}

.product .product-description {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.product:hover .product-description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.product-catalog {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-catalog">
    <div class="product">
       <a href="#">
          <div class="product-description">
           <a href="#" class="link">
            <span class="title">Название</span>
            <span class="price">Цена</span>
            <span class="categories">Категории</span>
            <span class="description">Описание</span>
           </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
       </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Это мне помогло, но результат немножко не тот, который мне требуется. Сейчас весь контент, заключённый в этот блок, идёт одной строкой, но мне необходимо, чтобы он был в несколько строк, но, когда доходит до границы блока, просто прерывался